# Организация работы потоков при обработке данных

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Доброе время суток, форумчане.

Только прочел о потоках, вследствие чего решил задачу:  есть список файлов (в `stringGrid`), каждый файл обрабатывается (очень долго) неким алгоритмом.

Код как бы рабочий, просто, может, чего недосмотрел. Посмотрите, пожалуйста:  я решил создать 2 потока (1-й для перебора файлов, 2-й для обработки каждого файла).

```
type  
  T_ListFiles = class(TThread) 
  private  
    PrProgress3: integer;  
    procedure SetProgress3;  
  protected  
    procedure Execute; override;  
 end;

type  
  T_ProcCalculate = class(TThread)  
  private  
    PrProgress4: integer;  
    procedure SetProgress4;  
  protected  
    procedure Execute; override;  
end;

PrSemaphore3: THandle;  
PrThLF: T_ListFiles;  
PrThPC: T_ProcCalculate;

//begin T_Thread1---------------------------------------------------------------  
procedure T_ListFiles.Execute; {перебор файлов, кол-во = 3шт.}  
var  
  i: integer;  
begin  
  for i := 1 to 3 do  
  begin  
    PrProgress3 := i;  
    Synchronize(SetProgress3);  
    if PrThLF.Terminated then  
    begin  
      PrThLF.Free;  
      exit;  
    end;  
    PrThPC := T_ProcCalculate.Create(false);  
    WaitForSingleObject(PrSemaphore3, infinite);  
  end;  
  CloseHandle(PrSemaphore3);  
  PrThLF.Free;  
  PrThPC.Free;  
end;

procedure T_ListFiles.SetProgress3;  
begin  
  Form1.Label6.Caption := IntToStr(PrProgress3);  
end;  
//end T_Thread1-----------------------------------------------------------------

//begin T_Thread2---------------------------------------------------------------  
procedure T_ProcCalculate.Execute; {обработка файла}  
var  
  i: integer;  
begin  
  for i := 0 to 100 do  
  begin  
    PrProgress4 := i;  
    sleep(100);  
    if PrThPC.Terminated then  
    begin  
      PrThPC.Free;  
      exit;  
    end;  
    Synchronize(SetProgress4);  
  end;  
  ReleaseSemaphore(PrSemaphore3, 1, nil);  
end;

procedure T_ProcCalculate.SetProgress4;  
begin  
  Form1.Gauge2.Progress := PrProgress4;  
end;  
//end T_Thread2-----------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  PrSemaphore3 := CreateSemaphore(nil, 0, 1, nil);  
end;

procedure TForm1.StartClick(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  PrThLF := T_ListFiles.Create(false);  
end;

procedure TForm1.abortClick(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  PrThPC.Terminate;  
  PrThLF.Terminate;  
end;
```

Заранее **спасибо**.

**Обновление**

Согласен, про многопоточность я перегнул (хотя наверняка можно было разбить список файлов на сдесяток потоков и значительно уменьшить общее время обработки). 
Но без нескольких потоков в моем приложении я не обойдусь, по той одной причине, что приложение во время обработки файла "вешается".

```
  Но все равно вопрос остается: я все правильно написал?
```

- Да я использую потоки, исключительно чтоб не морозить интерфейс.
- Поскольку я только столькнулся с потоками, я решил посмотреть взаимосвязь между ними + работу семафора (если это не тормозит работу, то я пока так и оставлю)
- Прогнал несколько раз CloseHandle, пока не увидел, но я еще не гонял программу
- А **вот можно поподробнее**, насчет логики создания/декремента счетчика/освобождения семафора, что именно не так?
- И еще вопрос: я правильно понимаю, то, что потоку все равно, какой семафор использовать - он использует первый попавшийся (т.е. поток не привязывается к семафору и наоборот)?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, при чем здесь многопоточность? У вас потоки выполняются один за другим. Строго.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, согласен. Сама задача не для многопоточности. Уважаемому @Konstantin78 следует уяснить себе, примерный круг задач, где многопоточность целесообразна и необходима. В частности, для управления интерфейсом во время "бесконечного" цикла (снятие данных эксперимента) и пр.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы решаете задачу параллельной обработки ста файлов, то неверно. Если используете потоки исключительно чтоб не морозить интерфейс, то достаточно одного потока.
ЗЫ Семафор тут не нужен. Для ожидания завершения потока есть TThread.WaitFor, который внутри использует уже имеющийся Handle потока. У вас логика создания/декремента счетчика/освобождения семафора не совсем корректная. При повторном запуске, например, CloseHandle даст invalid handle. И проверок не хватает.

**UPD**

Я изначально указывал, что задача либо не сформулирована, либо не та задача описана. Что касается функционала, реализованного в вопросе, то такого кода будет достаточно:

```
procedure T_ListFiles.Execute;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 3 do
  begin
    FProgress3 := i;
    Synchronize(SetProgress3);
    for j:=1 to 100 do
    begin
      FProgress4 := j;
      Synchronize(SetProgress4);
      if Terminated then break;
      Sleep(100);
    end;
  end;
end;

...

procedure TForm1.abortClick(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  PrThLF.Terminate;  
end;
```

а остальное аккуратно потереть.

Дальше возможны варианты:

- вынести первый цикл в GUI и запускать три потока, ожидать их выполнения, отлавливая окончание, например в `TThread.OnTerminate`...
- получить в gui список из 300 (3 по 100) файлов и запускать 300 потоков (в пуле по пять потоков одномоментно)
- ...

Запуск дочерних потоков из потока, запущенного из gui, т.е. третий уровень - лишнее усложнение логики.  Все прекрасно разворачивается в простой список, древовидность - излишняя сложность. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

Что касается семафора, то не думаю, что описывать, для чего он нужен и как с им работать, здесь уместно - в инете полно описаний и примеров. Скажем, это дополнительная задача, к коду в вопросе отношения не имеет. "Пусть останется"? - ну пусть, работает ведь... Семафор можно было бы использоваться в реализации, например, пула потоков... в будущем.

Относительно `CloseHandle`. Честно говоря, я никогда не имел желания проверять что будет при нарушении принципа "создал-удали", возможно исключение и не будет генерировано, возможно будет просто возвращено `INVALID_HANDLE`, в доках все написано, я бы на месте винды на `open;close;close;...close;` ругался, тут может оно и работает, но неаккуратно и непредсказуемо (глядя со стороны на код).

ЗЫ Есть реализации [пула](http://sourceforge.net/projects/threadpoolpas/), можно в них посмотреть как пул реализован, допускаю, что там как раз пользуются семафорами...

Comment: @Konstantin78, обновил ответ.